# Save custom objects when activty stops on Android

Tags: android, android-activity, storage

I've written a small andorid app. This app uses a vector of custom objects and displays them in a listview. I want to save those objects when the activity is send to background. What is the best way for this. In the vector are about 25 objects. Every object has a boolean, two long, and two strings.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

do you need them saved when the app shuts down or just when the activity goes into the background?

if your objects are parcelables you could use the save and restore instance state methods:

```
    @Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {

        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        outState.putParcelableArrayList("objectsArray", myObjects); // if its an array of parceleble objects

    }

    @Override
    protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
            myObjects= savedInstanceState.getParcelableArrayList("objectsArray");
    }
```

here is an example of a parcelable object

public class KNUserSketch implements Parcelable{

```
public int id;
public int user;
public String url;
public int views;
public int locations;


public KNUserSketch(JSONObject obj)
{
    id = KNSafeJSonUtilties.safeGetInteger(obj, "id");
    user = KNSafeJSonUtilties.safeGetInteger(obj, "user");
    views = KNSafeJSonUtilties.safeGetInteger(obj, "views"); 
    locations = KNSafeJSonUtilties.safeGetInteger(obj, "locations");
    url =  KNSafeJSonUtilties.safeGetString(obj, "url");
    Log.v("JSON","jsonObject: "+obj.toString());
    url.replace("https:", "http:");
}

public KNUserSketch(){
    id=-1;
    user=-1;
    views = 0;
    url ="";
}

public KNUserSketch(Parcel p){
    id= p.readInt();
    user = p.readInt();
    url = p.readString();
    views = p.readInt();
    locations = p.readInt();
}

@Override
public int describeContents() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return 0;
}

@Override
public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    dest.writeInt(id);
    dest.writeInt(user);
    dest.writeString(url);
    dest.writeInt(views);
    dest.writeInt(locations);
}

public static final Parcelable.Creator<KNUserSketch> CREATOR = new Creator<KNUserSketch>() {

    public KNUserSketch createFromParcel(Parcel source) {
        return new KNUserSketch(source);
    }

    public KNUserSketch[] newArray(int size) {
        return new KNUserSketch[size];
    }

};
```

}

Comment: no problem.. by the way.. you should use savedInstance states for anything that can never be null in your activity.. sometimes your activity goes into the background because the user has a call for instance.. while it is in the background the OS might garbage collect and when your activity returns, this could cause null pointer exceptions.. a good way to test for these instances is to go to the developer settings of your device and turn on "don't keep activities"

Answer (score 0):

You could use SharedPreferences to put the objets in a safe place, but objets will have to implement Parcelable protocol.